# All items in my pen drive had been renamed automatically and cannot open it

Tags: usb, usb-storage, usb-flash-drive

[image]

All the items (both files and folders) inside my pen drive had been renamed to some characters like **:]h.¡>?.A╕╗** and when I try to open any folder Windows gives this message.

**The filename,directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect**

I was told that it is a problem of the pen drive, not a virus. They say if I format the pendrive then I will be able to use it again normally. But I'm not sure. And I need those files.

Does anybody knows a solution?

Comment: Go to folder options, unckeck "Hide protected OS files" , select "Show Hidden files" and "Show file extensions". Post a screenshot of the drive here, may help

Comment: @Akash Thanks for the suggestion. I added a screenshot here.

Comment: It looks like your drive is trashed. Unfortunately, this sort of question is not programming related and is off topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @pabz Yup, looks like the drive would need a reformat. Have voted for a migration to superuser, people there would be able to help you better